# Proof of $a^{1/p}+b^{1/p}>(a+b)^{1/p}$ if $a$, $b$ and $p>1$

Tags: real-analysis

In a book, I saw the following:

For any two positive numbers $a$, $b$ and $p>1$, $a^{1/p}+b^{1/p}>(a+b)^{1/p}$. I tried to prove this but I was unsuccessful. Also, how is this inequality called, couldn't find any information online.

Comment: It should be $\ge$ instead of $>$as the case $p=1$

Comment: $2^2+3^2 \lt 5^2$ if $a=2, b=3 ,p=0.5 $

Comment: @Mark A. Ruiz Maybe you omitted some restrictions on the values your variables are allowed to take ?

Comment: Also, have you tried using Binomial Theorem for the proof ?

Comment: I would recommend start by proving $\frac{1}{2} \left(a^{1/p} + b^{1/p}\right) > \left(\frac{a + b}2\right)^{1/p}$, using $f(x) = x^{1/p}$ being a concave, and something like Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is false for $p <1$. For example $a^{2}+b^{2} < (a+b)^{2}$ for $a, b >0$ so the inequality does not hold for $p =\frac 1 2$. Suppose $p >1$. We claim that $c^{t}+(1-c)^{t} >1$ if $c,t \in (0,1)$. If this is proved we can take $c =\frac a {a+b}$ and $t =\frac 1 p$ to complete the proof. To prove the claim diferentiate w.r.t. $c$ to see that the function $c \to  c^{t}+(1-c)^{t}$ is strictly increasing for $c <\frac 1 2$ and then it strictly  decreases. Hence the inequality will follow if we prove that equality holds for $c=0$ and $c=1$ which is trivial.

Comment: you mean $p<1$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.

Comment: actually is for p>1, sorry about this, I can't seem to edit the question

Answer (score 0):

$a^{1/p}+b^{1/p}>(a+b)^{1/p}$ is false ! Consider the case $p=1/2$.

Comment: actually is for p>1, sorry about this, I can't seem to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if $a,b>0$ and $p>1$, you have an equivalence between
$$
(a+b)^{1/p} < a^{1/p} + b^{1/p}
$$
and
$$
a+b < \sum_{k=0}^{p} \binom{p}{k}a^{(p-k)/p} b^{k/p}, \\
a + b < a + b +  \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k}a^{(p-k)/p} b^{k/p}.
$$

The last inequality obviously is true and it is an equality if $a=0$ or $b=0$ or $p=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since both sides of inequality are homogeneous in $a, b$ of degree $1/p$ we can work with the assumption that $a+b=1$. Since $a, b$ are positive it follows that $0<a,b<1$ and $p>1$ so we have $$a^{1/p}+b^{1/p}>a+b=1=1^{1/p}=(a+b)^{1/p}$$